# write a php file in an extension that will always be included, no matter what

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions

Lets say I want to set general php things, like register to a shutdown function or do some ini_set() calls, and I want it to **always** happen whenever my extension works.

How can I do it, eg tell Magento "If this package is enabled, you must **always** include this php file"?

Note that I don't want to edit index.php or any of those files, it needs to come from the extension itself.

I though about using require_once() at the beginning of my files, but putting it in every file is kind of ugly.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you should add your own library by rewriting the autoloader of Magento, thus the require_once will always be called.

Check the second answer of this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417394/how-to-add-a-3rd-party-library-to-magento

Comment: thanks! I'm trying to use the controller_front_init_before event but can't seem to get it to work.. I tried putting it both inside the <frontend> tag and outside it. any ideas?

Comment: Try putting it inside the global tag. Add some logs to ensure it's getting called.

Comment: yeah that's what I did.. no logs are called :/ do you have by any chance an example of it working? from searching examples all I could find was people complaining about it not working but no working example.. thanks :)

Comment: Yeah, I've used that one some times ago to include composer library, I guess you can base your development on it: http://davemacaulay.com/how-to-include-composer-libraries-within-magento/